# XPath extraction issues (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, xpath

Recently, I found out how to read raw HTML with ruby and learned it's possible to incorporate XPath. I gave it a shot but I'm getting a myriad of errors that I've never seen. Anyone who knows what they're doing, please help.

My current code:

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'open-uri'
include REXML

file = open("https://www.sinister.ly/Forum-Coding--71")
lt = XPath(file, "//tid_60649")
puts lt
sleep
```

Comment: use [`nokogiri`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri)

Comment: Besides the advise to use `nokogiri`, even whether you are stuck to `REXML`, you have to init the object correctly: `REXML::Document.new(open("https://www.sinister.ly/Forum-Coding--71"))
`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers are pretty flexible about the HTML they read, but a library like rexml will not be. For parsing arbitrary websites Nokogiri is definitely the way to go. Try this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "https://www.sinister.ly/Forum-Coding--71"
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
res = page.search("//a[@id='tid_60649']").map {|match| match.text}
p res

=> ["[Ideas?] Reading raw HTML with Ruby"]
```

Comment: Getting a Load Error. Guessing it's because Nokogiri isn't a preloaded gem?

Comment: Yeah, you probably have to `gem install nokogiri`